# Using the word "he" twice in the same sentence - is this grammatically correct? If not, why are there published books that break this rule?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, sentence-patterns, repetition, is-it-a-rule

So, I was reading some books by Stephen King, S.D. Perry, and a couple authors I really love. I notice they'll use pronouns or certains words twice in the same sentence. When I read it, it's pleasant and doesn't sound weird in my head at all.

I assumed that if something is published under an author like Stephen King or Neil Gaiman, it must be grammatically correct to use something like "he" or "her" twice in the same sentence.

I'm not sure if this is why it doesn't sound strange in my head when I read it, but I've provided an example below. Here it is (bolded words are the repeated pronouns):

My example:

> Martin stared at the ceiling above and grimaced, counting the number
> of bumps and flecks embedded in its expensive paint. **He** gave up
> after some number **he** couldn't remember, tossed to his side, and
> yawned. The smell of curing lacquer and stain drifted off a nearby
> nightstand, burning his nose.

And here is another example from *It*, by Stephen King:

> When he grinned, there was a ghost of the handsome man he would become
> in the lines of his face.

There examples in multiple Stephen King novels of names repeated in the same sentence as well. I'm using Stephen King as an example, but note that **almost every published author I've read does this** in wildly different genres and styles.

Anyway, is using a pronoun more than once in the same sentence grammatically correct? I know sometimes things are grammatically correct, but discouraged or frowned upon, but that's not my question, here.

**tl:dr;** Is it grammatically correct to repeat a pronoun in the same sentence **in any circumstance**, *and if not,* why is there published material that violates this rule?

Comment: What rule do you think it's breaking?

Comment: I don't know if it breaks any rules. That's why I was asking.

Comment: If you keep the rule locked in your desk you're less likely to break it.

Comment: @M.Knepper  Why do you think that there's a grammar rule that prevents a pronoun being repeated in the same sentence? Clearly something made you think it was wrong or you wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @KillingTime I've typically been told you should never repeat a word in a sentence if possible by English teachers in high school. Edit: Added "...by English teachers in high school".

Comment: @M.Knepper Your comment starting "I've typically been told..." should be a central part of your question. Please edit to add in.

Comment: Repeating ***nouns*** in the same sentence is bad style. For example: **When the tree fell, the tree hit another tree on the tree's way down, and the second tree landed on our shed and crushed the shed.* This is why we have pronouns: *When the tree fell, it hit another tree on its way down, and the second one fell on our shed and crushed it.* Repeating pronouns is fine.

Comment: Repeating words of all grammatical categories is common. "Love is not love / Which alters when it alteration finds". "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure." "We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets"...

Comment: @Mitch I'm not trying to be rude, but I don't see how that changes anything? Whether or not someone on the street told me, or some teacher, or a professor, or a dream I had, or I just made it up, etc - the answer stays the same, right? I'll add it in if it does effect the answer, but I don't think it does?

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you, that makes plenty of sense. Reading your example of noun repitition immediately sounded strange and unpleasant versus pronoun reptition.

Comment: @M.Knepper that's not rude (unless you thought it was!). But your question's perspective changes how it should be answered best, even if it is a yes/no answer in the end. If you saw the rule in a book, we could ask for the exact quote and reference if it is a grammar rule or style suggestion . If you thought you heard it, we could address the misconception.

Comment: Grammatically you can't say 'the the' (which is the rule almost -all- words in English except for 'had had' and some informal emphasis like 'Do you -like- like him or just like him?'

Comment: But you can have lots of words multiple times Ina sentence grammatically and stylistically 'The man ride the horse's you can say 'The chestnut horse is bigger than the roan horse's but people usually will want to say '...the roan one'. It's not grammar forced on you but it is stylistically preferred  Most language cultures,  not just English, have this style preference. This for most verbs and nouns.

Comment: We have a tag called 'is-it-a-rule' that (I think) applies to the thrust of this question quite well: the poster wants to know if there is a rule against repeating a particular pronoun in a single sentence—presumably because someone at some point told the poster that doing so violated some stylistic or grammatical rule. The question isn't difficult to answer, but I don't think it follows that the poster has no business asking it at this site.

Comment: I'd like to know if in your language you can't repeat a pronoun....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically correct to repeat words in a sentence. There is no rule against this.

> I've typically been told you should never repeat a word in a sentence if possible by English teachers in high school.

This is in reference to some style but is not a strict rule.

Comment: Pretty concise answer. Thank you.

Comment: This "rule" doesn't make any sense at all. By that logic, you can't repeat "a" or "the" either.

Comment: Your teacher was just repeating what one of their teachers told them. That doesn't mean it's a grammar rule; it just means your teacher didn't learn grammar very well. And doesn't know the difference between speaking and writing.